# How do I center a button on a page?

Tags: html, css

I have a big problem centering a button I made. I don't mind if you give me the code in HTML or in CSS because I know both. In CSS I used this command `float:center;` and in HTML I used `align="center` but still it did not work. The funny thing is that when I went through codecademy it worked perfectly. Maybe safari does not support those features but it should support it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you attach your current code on your question or else everyone is stuck with guessing. What is `float: center`?

Comment: Please provide the code you've written. It likely can be fixed with a style of `text-align:center` on the buttons parent element, but it is hard to say for sure without your code.

Comment: `float:center` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need:

```
text-align: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your page is structured there are different methods for achieving this: 
[**JSfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/j0jdu01s/)

*Button as a standalone element:*
Here you want to treat the button as a `block` element as set it's left and right margins to `auto`.

```
<button class="btn">button 1</button>

.btn {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

*Button as an inline child element:*
In this case, you want to apply `text-align: center;` to the parent element.

```
<div class="btn-parent">
    <button class="btn-child">child button</button>
</div>

.btn-parent {
    text-align: center;
}
```